# Jsoup select command

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup

This is the first time I am trying to use Jsoup.
I am not able to understand the "select" operation.

```
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
```

This means that the in the page that is given as input search for src and select that line.
so, I can be able to read that text using src.tagname, src.width and all...

what does the following mean?

```
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
```

I am bit confused can you explain me what does a[href] mean and how to use it

Comment: It's explained in its documentation: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax It are just [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/PR-css3-selectors-20091215/). It's so much easier to understand if you've already some basic HTML/CSS experience.

Comment: Thank you the issue is : if you see this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India . In that I want to have all the Names in States of India only. But there are other tables also , when I do doc.select("area[title]"); I am getting all the table information . so I am looking if in select I can tell how it is used to only for a particular table

Answer (score 1):

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

--> Selects all `a`-tags with an attribute `href`

**example:** `<a href="something">...</a>`

But as BalusC said before: take a look at [documentation about selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

---

**"area problem":**

`doc.select("area[title]")` selects all **elements** matching this, not the attribute!

If you need all names (= attribute `title`) you can use this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India").get();
Elements elements = doc.select("area[title]");

for( Element element : elements )
{
    String title = element.attr("title");

    // Do something with the title
    System.out.println(title);
}
```